# Popping the top 2 values from a stack, adding them and push them back

Tags: c++

Here's what I came up with, I just want the program to pop the first 2 values in the stack, calculate them and push the back into the stack...I've already created the functions required but there seem to be a problem with the function that adds the two numbers.

```
#include <iostream>   

using namespace std;
int Maxlenght=5;
class stackhouse{
private:
    int *CreateArray;
    int top;
public:
    stackhouse();
    bool IsEmpty();
    bool IsFull();
    void constructor();
    void Push(int);
    void Pop(int);
    void Sum();
    void Sub();
};
stackhouse::stackhouse(){
    CreateArray= new int[Maxlenght];
    top=-1;
}
bool stackhouse::IsEmpty()
{
    if (top==-1) return 1;
    else return 0;
}
bool stackhouse::IsFull(){
    if (top==Maxlenght-1) return 1;
    else return 0;
}
void stackhouse::Push(int number){
    top++;
    CreateArray[top]=number;
}
void stackhouse::Pop (int number){
    number=CreateArray[top];
    top--;
}
void stackhouse::Sum(){
    int number=7,sum=5;
    Pop(sum);
    Pop(number);
    sum+=number;
    Push(sum);
    cout<<sum;
}
void main(){
    int number;
    stackhouse stack1;
    stackhouse();
    cout<<"Please fill the stack...";
    stack1.Push(5);
    stack1.Push(2);
    cout<<"The sum is...";
    stack1.Sum();
}
```

Comment: If anyone can be bothered reading that code, my hat off to them. I suggest, Ahmed, that you indent it properly before expecting others to read it. BTW, you don't need backquotes around indented code blocks.

Comment: Marcelo Cantos, It is my first time to post a question on stack overflow... so I had problems pasting my code in their required format. Sorry!

Comment: You must have a very strange editor if code with proper indentation copy-pastes without them. In any event, you can fix it by editing the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Pop` function needs to either return `number` or pass `number` by reference; otherwise, the assignment to `number` has no effect.

```
void stackhouse::Pop(int& number) {  // <-- add the &
    number = CreateArray[top];
    top--;
}
```

Or

```
int stackhouse::Pop() {
    int number = CreateArray[top];
    top--;
    return number;
}
```

(Note that the second way requires you to write `sum = Pop()` instead of `Pop(sum)`.)

Answer (score 1):

Passing a parameter by value to the pop() method is pointless. It needs to *return* a value.